# Server not responding to POST data sent via PHP and CURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to replicate a form submission that pulls back some analytics data using CURL in PHP. I have copied the raw POST from fiddler and used it to inform my PHP script.

This is my CURL function

```
function executeCurl($data, $certificate=false) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $data['header']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $data['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data['postdata']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $data['post']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $data['cookie']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data['httpheader']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    if($certificate) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt"); 
    }

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I receive a response from the server but the post data has been ignored. This is my POST request.

```
POST /report.aspx?tid=3477 HTTP/1.1
Host: blah.com
Cookie: somecookies;
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://blah.com/report.aspx?tid=3477
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Content-Length: 7418
Expect: 100-continue
```

The $data['postdata'] value is an exact copy of the url encoded data string that I copied from Fiddler. The rest of the headers are identical except the Expect: 100-continue header, which is added by CURL.

You can see the content type is set appropriately.

Additionally, HTTPS is being used and it makes no difference whether I use the certificate or not.

So, I get a response from the server but the post fields are ignored. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT adding "Expect:" to my HTTPHEADER means the POST now looks as follows, but the server still does not respond to the posted data.

```
POST /report.aspx?tid=3477 HTTP/1.1
Cookie: blah
Host: blah.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://blah.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://blah.com/report.aspx?tid=3477 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Content-Length: 7418
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by visiting the page twice. Once to retrieve the __VIEWSTATE, PagePostbackID, and PublicKeyToken variables.

The second time I used these variables in my request and the POST worked.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, cURL won't send the payload unless the server responds with 100 Continue after receiving that header. Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));` to disable this expectation.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've changed the header and I'm now returned an error page but it's one step closer to the result!

Comment: Ok, I was mistaken there. It returned an error because I had replaced my entire HTTPHEADER array with an array only containing "Expect:", hence the error.

Adding "Expect:" to my already defined array removes Expect from the POST call but the server does still not respond to the posted data. See Edit in question.